# returning an image when searched for by name

Tags: python, mysql, tk-toolkit

I'm Trying to make a function that searches the database when the search button is clicked within the gui which will then display the image saved with the keyword that was used in the search for example. Make: Tesla Model: Model s "then I click search and it should display that img of the car"

```
  connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="vehicle")
  cur = connection.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT make, model, img FROM car where make=%s, model=%s",self.make_txt.get(),self.model_txt.get())
  row=cur.fetchall()
            
  image = row[0][0]
            
  binary_data = base64.b64decode(image)
            
  image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(binary_data))
            
  image.show()

           
                          
  messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations!","car found!",parent=self.window)
  self.reset_fields()
except Exception as e:
  messagebox.showerror("Error!",f"Error due to {str(e)}",parent=self.window)
```

I keep getting an error saying "Error due to execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" any feedback would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. You need AND in your SQL statement and the parameters should be passed as an iterable (e.g., list or tuple). Therefore:

```
cur.execute("SELECT make, model, img FROM car where make=%s and model=%s", (self.make_txt.get(), self.model_txt.get()))
```

...should solve that particular issue